# $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\cos^{2}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(1-\cos x\right)}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\cos^{2}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(1-\cos x\right)}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\left(1-O\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)\right)^{2}\left(1-1+O\left(x^{2}\right)\right)}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\left(1-2O\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)+\left(O\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)\right)^{2}\right)O\left(x^{2}\right)}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{O\left(x^{2}\right)-2O\left(x^{2}\right)\cdot O\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)+O\left(x^{2}\right)\cdot\left(O\left(\frac{1}{x^{4}}\right)\right)}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{O\left(x^{2}\right)-2\cdot O\left(1\right)+\left(O\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)\right)}{x}$$

$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}O\left(x\right)-2\cdot O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+\left(O\left(\frac{1}{x^{3}}\right)\right) = O\left(\frac{1}{x^{3}}\right)$$

Therefore, the limit doesn't exist.

Did I evaluate it correctly?

Update: the answer is supposed to be 0.

Comment: Or you can simply write $(1-\cos x)=2\sin^{2} \frac{x}{2}$ and $\cos^2 \frac{1}{x}$ is already bounded.

Comment: It is true that $\cos(\frac{1}{x}) = 1 + O(\frac{1}{x^2})$ as $x \rightarrow 0$, but this is not because of the Taylor expansion (the terms there get more and more significant!) but rather simply because $\cos(anything) = O(1)$ and $1 = O(\frac{1}{x^2})$ as $x \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: the problem is that the limit is supposed to exist and be 0.

Comment: The problem with big $O$ notation is that you in the end found that your function was $O$ of something that diverged to $\infty$ as $x \rightarrow 0$. But big $O$ is a "less than or equal to" relationship. So this is not useful.

Comment: @aes, I didn't think about it that way. Thank you. So, basically, any finite number satisfy my result, right?

Comment: Yes, anything that has a limit as $x \rightarrow 0$ (and many things that don't) are $O(\frac{1}{x^3})$ as $x \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: "Did I evaluate it correctly?": no, your substitution of $\cos^2(1/x)$ is wrong as the argument goes to infinity.

Comment: Could you please explaind how to make it correctly?

Comment: @AvaSkovko As Mann said, or use the fact that $\cos(\frac{1}{x}) = O(1)$ and $\frac{O(1)O(x^2)}{x} = O(x)$, so the whole thing is $O(x)$, so close enough to $0$ it's less than a constant times $x$, so it goes to $0$ as $x \rightarrow 0$. (It is in fact useful that it's "lower or equal order" compared to $x$, because this one is small enough to limit to $0$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much simpler (and no asymptotic analysis required): it it is enough to observe that

$0\le \cos^2\dfrac1x\le 1\,$ and $\,\,\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\cos x-1}x=\cos'0 =0$.